# position control of uav

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, uav, simulator-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys , i would like to create a node for position control.
It should get current position values and the target position values .
For control i want to use a common PID Control for each coordinate.The node should output cmd_velocity message (geometry_msgs/Twist topic)

Is there maybe ready code for my goal?
Can i write a simple publisherfor that goal? So it is possible that a common publisher communicate with a gazebo plugin?
How the code might look like?

thanks
adrian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29172/position-control-of-uav/) by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2012-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you could check this, http://www.ros.org/wiki/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg .

---

Originally posted by [Mike Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/1629/mike-gao/) with karma: 108 on 2012-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on 2012-03-06**:
sorry,this link doesnt exist

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2012-03-06**:
I updated the link, should work now.

**Comment by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on 2012-03-07**:
i know that link but it doesnt help me.